# Immediate second view. Who's that?

Tags: support, view-counter

Whenever posting a question, it immediately get's viewed by at least one other user. Who's that? A mod, the community user,...?

Comment: it has been answered on meta:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259441/what-is-that-1-view-which-automatically-appears-after-submitting-a-question

Comment: @user2838619 I had a view, thanks...