# Does the "viewed" counter also count the poster's view?

Tags: support, view-counter

I looked but couldn't find the answer to this. I'm curious because every time I look at my recent posted question it has already 1 view. Maybe it's just coincidence?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the OP counts. They view the question, after all.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the OP's views are counted. See [Does the number of views on an SO question exclude my own views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122169/does-the-number-of-views-on-an-so-question-exclude-my-own-views) on meta.SE.

There is also this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on meta.SE: [Do not count views of the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/do-not-count-views-of-the-asker) (However, it did not receive much support.)

---

Since you have mentioned the 1 view immediately after posting the question, I will add also the following two links: [Immediate second view. Who's that?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22211/immediate-second-view-whos-that) and [What is that "1 view" which automatically appears after submitting a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259441/what-is-that-1-view-which-automatically-appears-after-submitting-a-question)